# 2D Array values are not getting assigned

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created an 2D array, and each contain the coin and the balance values, the problem is that the values for my 2D array don't assign to the array.
The values are correct and not empty, when I console.log them, they will output something.

```
async function getBalanceByCoin(account, coin) {
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(balanceOfABI, coin);
  const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(account).call();
  return web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether");
}

function checkBalance(account) {
  const coins = [usdc, stake, wnxm, bal, aleph, ampl, renbtc, ceth];
  const balances = coins.map(async (coin) => {
    const balance = await getBalanceByCoin(account, coin);
    console.log([coin, balance]); // Logs correctly and value prints out
    return [coin, balance];
  }).sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b[1]) - parseFloat(a[1]));


  return balances[0][1] === 0 ? 'None' : `${balances[0][0]}: ${balances[0][1]}`; // Values are not defined when logging 

}
console.log(checkBalance(account)) // Logs nothing, values are undefined:undefined
```

Comment: Your `balances` array (result of the map) is going to be an array of promises. You're treating them as if they are the balances.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was trying to await for .map, I needed to wrap it all up with `Promise.all`.
Here is the fix for it:

```
async function getBalanceByCoin(account, coin) {
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(balanceOfABI, coin);
  const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(account).call();
  return web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether");
}

async function checkBalance(account) {
  const coins = [usdc, stake, wnxm, bal, aleph, ampl, renbtc, ceth];
  const balances = await Promise.all(coins.map(async (coin) => { // Wrapped everything up in Promise.all()
    const balance = await getBalanceByCoin(account, coin);
    return [coin, balance];
  }))

  balances.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b[1]) - parseFloat(a[1]));

  return balances[0][1] === 0 ? 'None' : `${balances[0][0]}: ${balances[0][1]}`;

}
```